# Difference when running 'Cygwin.bat' and if just running 'bash' (.bash_profile vs. .bashrc)

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

When I am running `Cygwin.bat` I've got my all my custom stuff working from `.bash_profile` but when I am just running `bash` none of my stuff from `.bash_profile` is working and I am just got wired prefix like `root@comp:/mnt/c/cygwin64#` (as my current dir)

Is there any way to achieve the same result when running `bash` as I got when running `Cygwin.bat`

the content of `Cygwin.bat` is:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\Tools\cygwin64\bin

bash --login -i
```

Comment: `--login` is the difference

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @matzeri in the comment, `cygwin.bat` invokes `bash` with the `--login` option which creates an *interactive login shell*. And `bash` without the `--login` option creates an *interactive shell* which is not a *login shell*.

According to bash [man page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> When bash is invoked as an *interactive login shell*, or as a *non-interactive 
>   shell* with the `--login` option, it first reads and  executes  commands  from
>   the  file `/etc/profile`,  if  that  file exists.  After reading that file, it
>   looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and
>   reads and executes commands from **the first one** that exists and is readable.
>   The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this
>   behavior.
>
> When  an  *interactive  shell* that is *not a login shell* is started, bash reads
>   and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.  This may be
>   inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile` file option will force
>   bash to read and execute commands from file instead of `~/.bashrc`.

My `~/.bash_profile` has only one line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and I put all conf in `~/.bashrc`.