# aliases are not working on Linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, alias

i have created bunch of aliases in .bash_profile under root but those are not working.can anyone help what i am doing wrong

```
 # .bash_profile
 #shopt -s expand_aliases
 # Get the aliases and functions
 if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
     . ~/.bashrc
 fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/app/java
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export PATH

#Alias 
alias jfiles="cd /opt/app/Projects"
alias jscripts='cd /opt/app/Config'
alias jmres='cd /opt/app/tomcat/jmresources'
alias llrt='ll -r -t'
```

Comment: Did you `source` your `.bash_profile` after creating your aliases? Or start a new terminal?

Comment: `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`, is appropriate for aliases. The latter is run only for login shells, the former is run for every interactive shell (well, when you have your `.bashrc` sourcing it, as here). And, yes, you need to re-source `.bashrc` after editing it to take immediate effect.

Comment: For convenience, you can create a separate `.aliases` file, and read it in your `.bash_profile` similar to the few lines that read the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Evert, sure, but why would you do that rather than put them in `.bashrc` directly, since that file is already run in both pertinent cases (login shells when sourced from `.bash_profile`, and other interactive shells when invoked directly)?

Comment: @user7982813, ...you'll note the comment above where it sources `~/.bashrc` says "get the aliases and functions" -- there's a reason for that.

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940957/900078 (`.bashrc` vs. `.bash_profile`)

Answer (score 0):

The proper location for aliases should be .**bashrc** not **.bash_profile**
After adding aliases in .bashrc start a new login session or just run the .bashrc file i.e. **./.bashrc**