# Terminal opened in vim doesn't have .bash_profile sourced implicitly

Tags: bash, macos, vim

I am running vim 8.2 and when I execute the command "term" inside vim, it opens up a terminal in the same window but it doesn't have the .bash_profile sourced implicitly. I need to do that before using the terminal.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940957/900078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the bash man page:

.bash_profile is executed for login shells, while .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells.

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

Since you are using, non-login shell, I would suggest you to put all your aliases, shell options in the bashrc.

Comment: *"The bashrc will be sourced everytime you start bash."* -- this is not true.

Comment: When a "non-login shell" starts up, it reads the file "/etc/bashrc" and then the file "~/.bashrc", so should I have said 'shell' instead of 'bash' or there is something else I need to know, kindly provide some documentation where I can read more about it.

Comment: by default a login interactive shell would not source .bashrc. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940957/900078

Comment: I think I should have been more clear and added 'non-login shell' on the said line instead of thinking the context will be taken into account given that the answer was about non-login shell.

Comment: Thanks! I added pushd $HOME; source <mybash-includes>; popd to my .bashrc which made it work for me, especially since the terminal open the current working directory.