# Can't load .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell, nomachine-nx

**Backgroud:** I have 2 ways to login to my company's supercomputer: TeraTerm and NoMachine. TeraTerm is only terminal and it's faster. When I want to draw pics I use NoMachine.

**Problem:** I setup everything in my account .bash_profile, and it works when I use TeraTerm to login. But when it comes to NoMachine, I need to go to Konsole and `source .bash_profile`. Every time I disconnet and re-login, I need to source.

**What I did:** I use `echo $SHELL` to check currunt shell, use `ps` to check current process, use `echo $$` to check current process ID. I'm sure I use /bin/bash, not /bin/zsh or others.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the "NoMachine" is not starting login shells for you.

Solution:

1. Move all settings in `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.bashrc`.
2. Put only one line in `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

Comment: For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937077/